# Pandas Pivot over a List in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to pivot a pandas dataframe given a "list of components". The idea is to create 1 row per component (item of the list).

The dataframe columns looks like this

```
 Receipt      Items
 Receipt A   [id1, id2, id3, id4]
 Receipt B   [id4, id5]
 Receipt C   [id6, id7,id8]
```

What I need to obtain is a row per value (pivoting by Items):

```
 Receipt      Items
 Receipt A    id1
 Receipt A    id2 
 Receipt A    id3 
 Receipt A    id4
 Receipt B    id4 
 Receipt B    id5
 Receipt C    id6 
 Receipt C    id7
 Receipt C    id8
```

I'm new to Python and Pandas, and can´t imagine how to handle this situation, I need this to accomplish that format in order to apply more calculations in a data viz tool.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited to complete scenario**

```
 Receipt      Items                 Quantity
 Receipt A   [id1, id2, id3, id4]   [1, 3, 2, 1]
 Receipt B   [id4, id5]             [1, 2]
 Receipt C   [id6, id7,id8]         [1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [edit] your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [pandas explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
import pandas as pd

#your data here
A = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
B = ['id4', 'id5']
C = ['id6', 'id7', 'id8']

#create Dataframe with your data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Receipt':['Receipt A','Receipt B','Receipt C'], 'Items':[A, B, C]})

#printing your dataframe
print(df1)

#transforming through explode and print again
df2 = df1.explode('Items')
print(df2)
```

## output:

```
     Receipt Items
0  Receipt A   id1
0  Receipt A   id2
0  Receipt A   id3
0  Receipt A   id4
1  Receipt B   id4
1  Receipt B   id5
2  Receipt C   id6
2  Receipt C   id7
2  Receipt C   id8
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for, since I need to pivot 2 columns, in the complete scenario I will pivot each one in a new DF and merge them after that, I was looking around but couldn't find a better way to do it. Any suggestions?? Thanks again!